# Getting Internal server error (500) while redirecting to Paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, internal-server-error

We are getting an internal server error (500) while redirecting to Paypal.
Initially, it was random. But now we are getting this error almost in every request.

We are facing this issue in our two websites.

Is it a Paypal bug? or I'm doing any thing wrong?

We are redirecting it to the url:
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/it/cgi-bin/webscr

with following parameters:

```
item_name_1=classic
amount_1=170
item_number_1=a001
item_name_2=insurance
amount_2=60
item_number_2=c001
item_name_3=membership+fees
amount_3=15
item_number_3=001
amount=245
tax=0
business=<businessEmail>
return=<returnUrl>
cancel_return=<cancelUrl>
currency_code=EUR
custom=37ef7118-aff3-431e-a43d-e43a2005e721
cpp_logo_image=<logoImage>
notify_url=<notifyUrl>
no_shipping=0
quantity_1=1
quantity_2=1
quantity_3=1
```

Comment: Readers would probably need to see an example of your request going to PayPal, and what PayPal product you are using. A 500 error is not really much of a clue, since that's the most generic server error you can get.

Comment: You can probably check PayPay status systems, but in general that's unlikely to be the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above issue is no more. It has been resolved by PayPal itself. I got the response from PayPal Technical Support as they have been experiencing internal issues with the Sandbox environment and this should now be resolved.